# how to get loop value in other class objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have this code in bezier.m

```
for(int x = 0; x < [globalArray count]; ++x){
    NSInteger numOfCurves = [globalArray[x] count];
    UIBezierPath *linesegment = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for(int y=0; y< numOfCurves; y++){
        [UIBezierPath makeControlPoints:globalArray[x]];
        [UIBezierPath makeAnchorPoints:globalArray[x]];
        linesegment = [UIBezierPath makeTheCurve:globalArray[x]];
    }       

    strPaths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", linesegment];
    NSLog(@"log %@", strPaths);

    linesegment.lineWidth = [[self.linesWidth objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    linesegment.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    [linesegment stroke];
}
```

I need to get the value of "strPaths" past to viewcontroller.m which is the output is below

```
  log <UIBezierPath: 0x7fd50147ff30; <MoveTo {201, 130.5}>,
   <CurveTo {167.25000023841858, 130.6666666418314} {188.66666698455811,      130.33333332836628} {176.33333396911621, 130.16666665673256}>,
  <CurveTo {145.83333325386047, 134.75} {158.16666650772095,      131.16666662693024} {152.33333301544189, 132.33333325386047}>,
  <CurveTo {129.25000017881393, 146} {139.33333349227905, 137.16666674613953} 

    log <UIBezierPath: 0x7fd50147ff30; <MoveTo {201, 130.5}>,
       <CurveTo {167.25000023841858, 130.6666666418314} {188.66666698455811,            130.33333332836628} {176.33333396911621, 130.16666665673256}>,
       <CurveTo {145.83333325386047, 134.75} {158.16666650772095,      131.16666662693024} {152.33333301544189, 132.33333325386047}>,
       <CurveTo {129.25000017881393, 146} {139.33333349227905, 137.16666674613953}
```

and so on....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSUserDefaults for storing value as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:strPaths forKey:@"strPaths"];
```

and retrieve that data as given below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"strPaths"];
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: i have to this drawing lines value everytime I move touch it showing the control points. I need to gather all of that. edited my sample output.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways than NSUserDefaults. You can use delegation and pass those values from 'bazier.m' to 'viewcontroller.m'. Or use NSNotificationCenter with custom notification.

Answer (score 1):

Your first priority should be to write a `block` for this, and return the value through the `block` every time in the loop. (If you are calling a conceptually static function)

If not, your next priority should be to create a `delegate` for this class and pass the value back in the `delegate` method.

If that is also not possible, you should opt for `NSNotificationCenter` and post notifications to an observer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding -> [strSuccess appendString:strCoor];

```
NSMutableString *strSuccess = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
for(int x = 0; x < [globalArray count]; ++x){
    NSInteger numOfCurves = [globalArray[x] count];
    UIBezierPath *linesegment = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for(int y=0; y< numOfCurves; y++){
        [UIBezierPath makeControlPoints:globalArray[x]];
        [UIBezierPath makeAnchorPoints:globalArray[x]];
        linesegment = [UIBezierPath makeTheCurve:globalArray[x]];
        strCoor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", linesegment];
    }
    [strSuccess appendString:strCoor];
    strPaths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"======%@", strSuccess];

    linesegment.lineWidth = [[self.linesWidth objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    linesegment.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    [linesegment stroke];
}
```

thank you guys for the help.